# How to do social links with icons as a link field in a block?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have a footer that contains a simple contact information and underneath is a social follow set of links.

I created the block type, with the thought that the top part (Connect) is a WYSIWYG.

My second thought was to make the Follow Us just a link field with 5 values, but I want to add a little flexibility and for theming concerns, I need to know what link goes with which service.

[image]

Can I either do this with the link field, or can I reference a menu somehow and attach it to this block type? As a menu, I can rig up menu attributes. But if there is a more practical way, I would like to know how to do it.

I do not want to hard code it because they might change URLs or want to reorder the list of services at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task, for me was better creating a **Custom Block Type**, named 'Social networks' with one field of type 'Link'.

In this field you can configure how many links you can handle (remember once you create one block of this type, you'll cannot change this value).

Once this **Custom Block Type** was created you can configure 'Manage form display' and 'Manage display' if you need.

Now you'll be able to create a **Custom Block** of type 'Social Networks' that provide a couple of links that you can set/edit, rearrange and use proper template per block, and place where you want.

This was the solution found to not use any piece of code.